# Finding Basis of a Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find a basis of the subspace $U ⊂ \mathbb R^3$ which is spanned by ${u_1,u_2,u_3}$
with
$u_1 = (0, 1, 1), u_2 = (2, 4, 4)$ and $u_3 = (1, 1, 1)$.

I know these vectors are not linearly independent but that the set $V=$ {$u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$} spans $U$. Does that mean I can remove any one of the three vectors $u_1,u_2,u_3$ and define that as the basis ?

But there is no guarantee that that will then span the subspace ? Say if I remove $u_3$, I need to check if $a u_1 + b u_2 = u_3$? If that is true, then I can say that {$u_1, u_2$} spans V?

Comment: Write as the rows of a matrix. Do row reduction to create an upper triangular matrix (0's below the main diagonal). The 3, 2 (or 1) none zero  rows left are your basis.

Comment: @Paul brilliant. I had a row of zeros, so the other two rows form the basis ? Was the method I stated correct ?

Comment: The vectors $u_1, u_2$ are clearly independent. Since $u_3$ is a linear combination of them (if it wasn't then all $3$ vectors would be linearly independent), it follows that $u_1, u_2$ span all of $U$, and so it is a basis. In general, if you have a spanning set, then a maximal independent subset is a basis.

Comment: @Mark Okay thanks. So I was correct before but a little over complicated it ?

Comment: You can also form 3 by 3 matrix with these vectors as rows or columns. If determinant is non-zero, they are linearly independent and will form a basis. If determinant is zero, just observe if any two vectors are linearly independent or not (just check scalar multiple). If yes, such two vectors will form a basis. In this case, any of these three $\{u_1, u_2\},\{u_1, u_3\}, \{u_2, u_3\}$ will work as a basis.

Comment: @NikitaMazepin You can say that after removing $u_{3}$ that $\{u_{1},u_{2}\}$ is a basis if $u_{1},u_{2}$ are linearly indepdendent. Just recall the definition of basis. The constituents have to span the subspace as well as be linearly independent. So yeah the way you state is a "strategy"(Although not an optimal one) to find a basis for a subspace spanned by say $\{v_{1},...,v_{m}\}$. You keep removing vectors which can be expressed as a linear combination of the others till you reach the set which spans the subspace as well as is linearly independent. It is easier to do by Paul's suggestion.

Comment: @CroCo But in my example it was only a subspace of $ \mathbb R^3$

Comment: @CroCo I mean the whole space $U$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: @NikitaMazepin Pretty much. You can also use a matrix, as was suggested in the other comments. But here it's much easier to do it directly.

Comment: @Mark Question: I already know that $U$ has dimension $3$ do I not ? So if I prove let's say $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly independent, then I have proved it is a basis and don't need to check it spans $U$ anyway ?

Comment: The basis of U is 2 dimensional as you found, it is a plane.

Comment: @Paul Okay I understand everything now, thanks. So if the basis is $2$ dimensional, is it always a plane ? And if $1$ dimensional, a line ? Let’s say if it’s not just a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ but $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Lines and planes through the origin in 3D are the only subspaces yes. More generally subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$are called hyperplanes

Answer (score 0):

By definition, to determine a set a vectors are linearly independent or not, is to check the solutions for the following equation, (especially in your case)

$$x_1u_1+x_2u_2+x_3u_3=0$$

If, as you said, they are not linearly independent, then there exists at least one of $x_1, x_2, x_3$, such that it is not zero. As you said, for example, you found $x_3\neq 0$, then you can write above equation as:

$$u_3=-\frac{x_1}{x_3}u_1-\frac{x_2}{x_3}u_2$$

So in your notation,

$$a=-\frac{x_1}{x_3}, b=-\frac{x_2}{x_3}$$

This means $u_3$ can be expressed by the linear combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$. So if you want to find the basis, you can throw $u_3$ away, and only keep $u_1$ and $u_2$. But it is not done yet, next you need to check if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly independent. So you repeat the similar procedure,

$$x_1u_1+x_2u_2=0$$

to see if you can find non-zero solutions for this equation. For example,

Case.(1) If you can find non-zero solution for $x_2$, then above equation can be written as:

$$u_2=-\frac{x_1}{x_2}u_1$$

which means $u_2$ can be expressed by $u_1$, so you can throw $u_2$ away, then you get the basis for $U$ as: $\{u_1\}$.

Case.(2) If there is only all-zero solutions for $x_1, x_2$, then $u_1, u_2$ are linearly independent, then you get the basis for $U$ as: $\{u_1, u_2\}$.